# How do i iterate functions until convergence in R?

Tags: r, statistics, convergence

I am looking to iterate until convergence but I am not sure how i should code it.

A simple similar example is something like

$X_0=5 ,  Y_0=3$

for $n=1,2..$

$P_n=X_{n-1}-Y_{n-1}$

$Y_n=3P_n$

$X_n=P_n+Y_n$

and end when it converges.

I have seen that for the repeat loop it loops indefinitely with an exit condition but I am unsure how i can word the iterations  within R and how to word the exit condition for convergence. Any references or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to check that the change in your value of interest becomes very small, eg $abs(X_n - X_{n-1}) < eps$ where eps is a small number like 0.0001.